# Under what conditions the partialy ordered set of real valued functions becomes a chain?

Tags: order-theory

Let $P$ be a set of real valued functions defined on non empty set $X$ with partial order $\leq$ defined by $f \leq g \iff f(x) \leq g(x) \forall x \in X$
Under what circumstances is P a chain ?

Comment: By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition): if all elements of $P$ are comparable, i.e. for every $f,g\in P$ we have $f\leq g$ or $g\leq f$.

Comment: But when that's going to happen

Comment: If you are after sufficient conditions for that then your question is simply too broad. One example: $P$ only has one element. There are plenty other examples.

Comment: One interesting condition, spamming the notion of Hardy fields, is when elements of $P$ are definable in an o-minimal structure $(X,\preceq,...)$. Note however that the order $\leq$ has to be weakened to authorize $f \leq g$ iff $\exists a \in X, \forall x \geq a, f(x) \preceq g(x)$.